# Lenovo SR530 Server turns off abruptly and unexpectedly and won't turn on unless I reconnect power

Tags: bios, power-supply, shutdown, lenovo-desktop-computer, thinkcentre

so I just got a Lenovo SR530 Server for hosting a web-based program on or a medical facility, nothing too fancy but just to help run the business a bit easier and give better access to data storage and retrieval. The server is running on a more than appropriate APC UPS.

I got the server running normally a while ago with my web-based app and corresponding websites running well and all of a sudden the server would just turn off in any state.

The server would turn off regardless of whether I'm on the XClarity Provisioning Manager or Booted into OS.

I have tried reinstalling the OS, Removing the RAID configuration and reseating the SSDs, Reseating the RAM, Disconnecting the CMOS battery and let it sit for a few days, updating and resetting the BIOS and the BMC, reseating the power supply into a different slot. It just doesn't work.

I've done everything in my power to try to make sure it doesn't just turn off on me but it always keeps doing it. Neither diagnosis from the BIOS nor a hardware diagnosis show that anything is wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you contact Lenovo / IBM Server Support?

Comment: I did, waiting to have someone get back to me on this issue.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ but they will want a lot more info; e.g. what is running and why, any logs etc